# how to create the scrolling Menu in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wants to create something like this

[image]

Actually I really don't know what t0 call if anybody know then let me know so I can search also on google.

when we click on the arrow the other result should come
I will be having manny fixtures

I was thinking about

1> A table having a column and show them one by one

2>a dynamic list having the whole list?

Suggestions Required.

I am not knowing anything about the css and javascript for this can you please show me some path for this.
Thank you.

Comment: that's called a [carousel menu](https://www.google.dk/search?q=carousel+menu+jquery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some amendments to Tim4497's method.

This method allows for any number of list items, and has the advantage of being a pure Javascript solution (no JQuery required!)

This method arranges list items horizontally through means of `float: left`, and then causes a break in the list by setting the `ul` element to a fixed width of `400px`. Elements that overflow are hidden by `overflow: hidden`.

```
var list_items = [];
var index = 0;
var list_length = 0;

function getAllListItems() {
    var temp = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        list_items.push(temp[i]);
    }

    list_length = temp.length;
}
```

The following function

```
function move(dir){}
```

is attached to a button element as follows :

```
<button id='right' onClick='move(right)'>></button>
```

and it intelligently hides the correct element to give the effect of moving right.

```
function move(dir) {
    if (dir == left) {
        list_items[index].style.display = 'block';
        index--;

        if (index < 0) {
            index = 0;
        }
    } else if (dir == right) {

        list_items[index].style.display = 'none';

        if (index >= ((list_length) - 1)) {
            index = (list_length) - 1;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    } else {}
}
```

[Relevant JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrw3daqc/)

Comment: and what about if I press arrow and I am showing three Items so other three Items Should be shown not next?

Comment: @SandhyaGor I'm not sure what you mean, can you rephrase?

Comment: like in your e.g u r showing 3 items at a time and when u click next the next list is appear so how can I replace all 3 with next 3?

Comment: that would require quite a significant alteration of the javascript, i can do it but this margin is too small to contain it...

Answer (score 1):

create them as li objects, float them inline or left, give them all the same width e.x. 100px then make a wrapper with overflow hidden (wrapper must be smaller than all li objects combined)
with a bit off js you can set that if you click on an arrow the wrapper scroll 100px to the left or to the right

```js
$( ".arrow" ).click(function() {
    $( "ul li:first-child" ).hide();
});

$( "#2" ).click(function() {
    $( "ul li:first-child" ).show();
});
```

```css
.arrow{width:50px;background-color:gray;}

ul
{
width:500px;
height:50px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
overflow:hidden;
}

li {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow">Right</div>
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>NOW VISIBLE</li>
</ul>
<div id="2" class="arrow">Left</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not getting what you are saying